# Is there a regex double-quote matching syntax that can be used without modification in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

The following simple regex includes four double-quotes that must be matched.  I'm not attempting to come up with a solution for this particular regex but am merely using it as a general example:

```
\s*"Hello"\s*"world"\s*
```

The problem I've always encountered when writing C# code that contains regexes that must match double-quotes is the cumbersome syntax I've had to use because string literals in C# are double-quote delimited.  I've used the two different techniques below, neither of which I like.  Aside from the additional complexity required to butcher the original regex into acceptable C# syntax, converting that syntax back into the original regex for additional development is a real pain.  Is there any form that would be equally acceptable to both the regex engine and the C# language parser?

The first hack uses escape characters to escape the backslashes and double quotes that must appear literally in the regex.  I view this as the most error prone approach because you get buried in backslashes for more complex regexes:

```
"\\s*\"Hello\"\\s*\"world\"\\s*"
```

The second hack breaks the original regex into multiple pieces and concatenates them.  Pieces that are string literals and contain regex backslashes are preceded by an @ character to cause the backslashes to be taken literally rather than as escape characters.  I view this as more verbose but less error prone than the previous approach:

```
@"\s*" + '"' + "Hello" + '"' + @"\s*" + '"' + "world" + '"' + @"\s*"
```

Comment: Why was this question voted down?

Answer (score 0):

`@"\s*""Hello""\s*""world""\s*"` gives the string `\s*"Hello"\s*"world"\s*`. Simply double the double quotes in an `@` prepended string (AKA verbatim string) to display a double quotes

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jwmEGF)

Comment: Although this is not quite what I was asking for, if your regex development application has a built-in converter between regex and C# strings like RegexBuddy does, this is a pretty clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that by using the hex escape sequence \x22 to represent a double quote the same regex string can be used unaltered both in my regex development application (RegexBuddy) and in a C# string literal.  That is, in my development application

```
\s*"Hello"\s*"world"\s*
```

can be represented directly as

```
\s*\x22Hello\x22\s*\x22world\x22\s*
```

and in a C# string literal the same regex string it can be represented as

```
@"\s*\x22Hello\x22\s*\x22world\x22\s*"
```

The string is still cluttered but at least no changes are required.